# Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904 while working with document library programmatically : SP2010

Tags: 2010, development, document-library

I am working with Document Library programmatically in SharePoint 2010. Several time it gives the error

```
15705   Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131904     at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponseStream(Stream responseStream)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ProcessResponse()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQueryToServer(ChunkStringBuilder sb)
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRequest.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientRuntimeContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ClientContext.ExecuteQuery()
   at ErrorLocation
Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime 2016-10-19 07:01:57.030
```

I am not getting the exact reason. I already went through all the post over this network which says that this is the issue with Content DB.

My content DB size is 2.6GB around and the server over which the SharePoint and SQL has been installed have more than 76 GB of free space available.

Help me out to resolve this issue. I am not getting what I am doing wrong.